# Is Directory.CreateDirectory asynchronous or what?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code to prepare a folder for files I generate:

```
if (Directory.Exists(outputDir))
{
    Directory.Delete(outputDir, true);
}
Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);
```

When I run it normally, exactly every second time it works, and the other time it throws a `DirectoryNotFoundException`, on the line:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, CreateRows(TestLineCount, TestSampleCount));
```

saying `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Dev\Android\Projects...`. The last folder in the `filePath` is missing, because I deleted it, but then I created it again, so it should always be there. When I put a break point on the line `Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);`, and there is a small delay, the app works every time. If I introduce an automatic delay, i.e:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

It also works every time. Surely all these calls should block until finished, so the `outputDir` is always there?

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace because CreateDirectory has a check just before it returns to verify the folder is created and if not throws. So I'm wondering where in the FileStream.Init it fails, assuming that method is at the top of the call stack. On which OS is this btw?

Comment: Please post code that actually reproduces the issue and the full exception including its call stack. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()`. `CreateDirectory` isn't asynchronous. Are you working with remote shares perhaps?

Comment: After executing your first codeblock, when the directory which should be deleted is large enough, then CreateDirectory fails sometimes. Fails means no directory will be there after that codeblock. Seems to be a bug in case it is meant to be sync...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Think that it is not asynchronous but when you call this like that

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir); //App is trying to create directory
//successfully created but depends on OS how fast OS commits the changes

Thread.Sleep(500); //assuming physically creation on Hard and its availability in OS took less then 500ms then this wait works or else we have to wait more

//this delay is actually totally non generic since the time differs OS to OS


 // its just a rough guess that changes will be committed within 500ms

if(!Directory.Exists(outputDir))
  //if still not exists Your OS que is being processed very slow due to 
  //some not known reason! so you have to wait more then 500ms
```

Comment: Then that's actually a bug. It `CreateDirectory` shouldn't return at all until the changes are committed. I would only expect that from `CreateDirectoryAsync`.

Comment: @ProfK where did you find `CreateDirectoryAsync`? I've heard it was available in WinRT but googling for it returns irrelevant results. Anyway, `CreateDirectory` isn't asynchronous. Post the full exception (including its call stack) and code that actually reproduces the issue

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't find `CreateDirectoryAsync`. I said blocking `CreateDirectory` is behaving as if it was async.

Comment: @ProfK not according to the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,221). Anyway, it's a metadata operation that takes so little time *locally* that you don't even need it to run asynchronously. Things are different with shared folders though. *Deleting* all files and folders on the other hand takes a lot of time because each file and folder has to be deleted individually. *Maybe* `Delete` returns earlier than it should. Or not. Hard to tell without the path, stack. . Anyway, `CreateDirectory` returns a `DirectoryInfo` you can use to check for existence